# Encrypting, then storing access token in localStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, jwt

My API returns an access token after a user signs in.

All future requests must include this token in the Authentication header.

I'd like users to remain logged in even if they close and re-open the browser.

Can I safely store an encrypted version of this access token in localStorage, retrieve it, unencrypt it in my React client code and send it off to the API?

Comment: You _can_, but if you control the API you may want to consider using cookie based storage and preventing access via CORS. This prevents XSS attacks from obtaining access to encrypted authentication data.

Comment: https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2011/august/javascript-cryptography-considered-harmful/

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/173620/what-s-wrong-with-in-browser-cryptography-in-2017

Comment: I would recommend you to move away from local storage to keep sensitive information, it is not safe. At work, we have a bunch of single-page applications using cookies to keep the access token of the user, which is a much safer solution.

You can read more about why we should be using cookies instead of local storage to keep sensitive information in this link: https://dev.to/rdegges/please-stop-using-local-storage-1i04

Answer (score 5):

Sure, you could use something like this https://www.npmjs.com/package/aes-js or another library if you like at https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=keywords:encrypt.

I think the real question is why? The user can always see the unencrypted value in the network request of the dev tools. If the access token is tied to a username and password that the user owns why can't they see it? It's really just another way to write their username and password. If it is associated with an username that belongs to your app (such as your server uses that username to login to another server for all requests, not just for this one user) then you shouldn't pass it to the browser ever because it is easy to steal.

Comment: It could be useful in the case of an attacker steal the JWT token so you can keep its information safely. As much as data you hide it's better in this case.

Comment: so encrypting the token could be useful on preventing some XSS attacks?

Comment: If you are using a JWE token, user won't be able to see the contents of the token in the network request. So, I think it is a good option to encrypt the JWE token and store it in local storage. We can use dotenv to store the secret key in env file. The idea here is to prevent a malicious user from stealing your jwe token from the localstorage and impersonating you. I am naive on security aspects. Just sharing my thought. Can someone please correct me if I am wrong?